# Android: How can I POST json while loading the response in a WebView?

Tags: android, json, post, webview

I have a page that will be loaded using a WebView, but it is expecting POSTed json in the request. Nothing I have found on POSTing data seems to make sense in terms of receiving HTML as a response.

Any help would be appreciated.

In particular, it seems using `WebView#postUrl`, I am stuck with the default `content-type`.

The `WebView#loadData` has some weird "you can't load resources from the network" clause if you use this approach.

Really, this seems surprising to me. Is it that strange of a request to want to POST some data when requesting a page? iOS does this with no problem.